# asp.net application performance and stress testing ? Please guide

Tags: asp.net, performance

thanks for your attention and time.

I want to test asp.net application for stress, load and performance. Please guide me what free tools should be used for this ? Is there any tool which particularly can be used to analyse individual components, functions and scripts and resources they use ?

Thanks in anticipation for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynaTrace is a client-server web performance tool. The client part, called [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/), which is free, is a complete performance testing tool. It traces asynchronous JavaScript executions, including full round-trip time, and reports performance by method or event. V 2.0 Beta is just came up, and seems to be pretty stable and more powerfull than other popular and free browsers performance testing add-ons (Firebug, Yslow, etc.).

The server part of dynaTrace is designed to test ASP.NET code-level performance, but it's not free. So check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308816/any-good-free-net-profiler) stackoverflow topic to see if any free .NET code profiles will work for you.

To test your app under the load you need to use a load generator. Check out the free [Microsoft Web Capacity Analysis Tool WCAT 6.3](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6) that allows to simulate various load scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of :

[ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/)

[Add-ons for Firefox Extensions Load Time Analyzer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3371/)

[Add-ons for Firefox Extensions Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)